# "Hundreds of applicants" vs "hundreds of resumes"

Tags: grammar, objects

When I am referring to a number of job applicants, I might say, "I've got a hundred qualified applicants in this folder"; when what I mean is, "I've got RESUMES from a hundred qualified applicants in this folder".

Although most English speakers would understand what I meant, it is not proper English. Is there a name for this grammatical shortcut/faux pas?

Although the Web has powerful search capabilities; unless you KNOW the name of something, it is hard to search for it. I am very grateful for all the StackExchange sites.

Comment: Well, it might be the figure-of-speech known as *synecdoche*.  But I would not call it a faux pas, nor would I say it is not proper English.

Comment: @GEdgar *Synecdoche* is more often used to refer to the figure of speech in which a part is used to refer to the whole - *forty roofs were lost to the wildfires*. A *resume* is a term associated with *applicant* but neither the part or the whole.

Comment: Saying "applicants" could be better than saying "resumés" if the folder might contain multiple resumés for some applicants, and/or describe applicants for whom resumés were not enclosed.  I consider the usage similar to saying a company's added thousands of new products to its latest catalog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"*A hundred qualified applicants in this folder*" is perfectly grammatical, and a reasonable turn of phrase; it is an example of [metonymy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy):-

> a figure of speech in which a thing or concept is called not by its
>   own name but rather by the name of something associated with that
>   thing or concept

Comment: Thank you, I thought it was correct but wanted to make sure. Now I know the term metonym, as well as synedoche.